# Modifing SDK silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am modifying CRM 2011 SDK silver-light application "restsilverlightcontacteditor"
I am little confuse about binding path.
Can anyone explain me about this.

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="FirstNameTxt" Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="LastNameTxt" Header="Last Name"  Binding="{Binding Path=LastName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="PhoneTxt" Header="Phone" Binding="{Binding Path=Telephone1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="EmailTxt" Header="Email"  Binding="{Binding Path=EMailAddress1, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="StreetTxt" Header="Street" Binding="{Binding Path=Address1_Line1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Data Binding in Silverlight (and WPF) is a way for the UI to have a relationship with data, other than manually setting the UI element's values. It establishes a relationship between a UI control's properties with a property of another code object, usually a model or view model.

In the code you've provided, the Bindings describe how the data in the DataGrid gets bound to each column. The data is bound from the DataContext property. DataContexts are inherited by children. In this case, the DataGridTextColumns are children of a parent element, who's DataContext they will inherit. Since you haven't provided us that code, I can't point it out to you.

This should provide some useful reading:

[Data Binding in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)